# Seeing/dumping incoming data on a port?

Tags: socket

I need to check if some client is sending some data on a specific port of a raspberry pi/debian or windows. Is there some built in program that I can launch to check a particular port for incoming data/tcp, and possible dump it on screen or log ??

Answer (score 0):

Look into tcpdump.  That should meet your requirements.